# Displaying data of Firebase into simple HTML page

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was wondering how I could display multiple rows of data in Firebase onto a blank page/simple website.

I am currently using this to display a simple string:"Testing" through this method:

```
var bigOne = document.getElementById('bigOne');

var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child('text');

dbRef.on('value', snap => bigOne.innerText = snap.val());
```

[How it looks in Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ1XW.jpg)

[How it looks on a blank site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBH40.jpg)

But how can I display multiple lines/rows of data from Firebase onto the blank page?

With multiple lines/rows of data I mean this: 
[Firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiqSr.jpg)

EDIT: This is my current code: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPLad.jpg)

However it shows nothing on my HTML page. Do I have to add this line of code back or adjust it? If I add it back it says: [object Object] on the site.

```
dbRef.on('value', snap => bigOne.innerText = snap.val());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen to a list of items and loop over the items:

First you should adapt your dbRef to

```
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref('sensor/dht');
```

then query as follow

```
var tempo = '';    
dbRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    tempo += 'temp: ' + childSnapshot.val().temp + ' - humidity: ' + childSnapshot.val().humidity + '<br>';   //Just an example of formatting the output
  });
  bigOne.innerText = tempo;
});
```

Have a look a the doc at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists

Comment: So snapshot would be: "sensor"
and childSnapshot: "dht" right? or do I just leave it like this (your example)?


Also could you maybe give me an example of how to display the humidity & temperature on a single page?

Comment: @Xyrai I have adapted my answer, following your comment

Comment: I tried your answer out but it shows me a blank page, any idea why? 

Also do I have to remove this line?:

dbRef.on('value', snap => bigOne.innerText = snap.val()); because in the end you use bigOne.innerText = tempo;

Comment: No you don't have to add this line back since we already query with dbRef. Actually I've just realised that there is a typo in my code: I referred to ref and not dbRef. I have corrected my answer. What you can also do is add console.log(tempo); before the line bigOne.innerText = tempo; and look in the javascript console that you get the correct values.